# How can I split my string using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string:

```
abcdefgh1234.1.1.t1111-1.16.2222.1-1.t67_76.txt
```

How can I split it into the following pieces using a regex?

```
abcdefgh
1234.1.1
t1111
1.16.2222.1-1
t67_76.txt
```

Comment: try http://txt2re.com/

Comment: What determines where to split?

Comment: Can we not split it the first time based on only alphabets eg. [A-Z][a-z] and then the first occurrence of a number [0-9] and so on ?

Comment: How do you mean "the first occurrence"?

Comment: There is too much overlap of like characters to do a split. You'd be better off using a matching regex with capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

On your input string, this works:

```
^([a-z]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+){2})\.([a-z]\d+)\-(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}\-\d)\.([a-z][\d_]+.\w+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1KiUI6LHnZyi3hAm)

Each element you want is in its own capture group.

Comment: Updated to match only lowercase letters in capture group one, and any lowercase letter where you have a single `t`. Just change them back to `t` if it's never anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how to split, so here's a guess:

```
my @fields = /^(\D+)([\d.]+)\.([^-]+)\-([\d.\-]+)\.(.*)\z/ or die;
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only string you want to split, or if every string is formatted in that way (the splitting seems quite arbitrary to me), this will do:

```
([a-z]+)([\d\.]+)\.(\w+)-([\d\.-]+).([\w+\.]+)
```

Extract the matching groups, and you're done.

`$1` is the first part, `$2` is the second part, and so on.